# Using PerWcfSession lifestyle with Castle WCF Integration Facility

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

The following code uses the Castle Windsor 3.0's [WCF Integration Facility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=WCF-Integration-Facility&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to register a WCF self-hosted service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;

using Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace SelfHost
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        private readonly PerSession _perSession;

        public HelloWorldService(PerSession perSession)
        {
            _perSession = perSession;
        }

        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0} {1}", name, _perSession.Info());
        }
    }

    public class PerSession
    {
        private readonly string _now;

        public PerSession()
        {
            _now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        public string Info()
        {
            return _now;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();

            container.Register(
                Component.For<PerSession>().LifeStyle.PerWcfSession(),
                Component.For<IHelloWorldService>()
                    .ImplementedBy<HelloWorldService>()
                    .AsWcfService(
                        new DefaultServiceModel()
                            .AddBaseAddresses(baseAddress)
                            .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding()).At("basic"))
                            .PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())
                    )
                );

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to invoke the SayHello method using WcfTestClient.exe results in the following error:

> Could not obtain scope for component SelfHost.PerSession. This is most
>   likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to
>   access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request
>   component outside of web request etc)

What is the correct way to use PerWcfSession components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was missing a few things:

The ServiceContract needs to set the SessionMode property

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

Likewise the ServiceBehavior needs to set the InstanceContextMode

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

Finally, the service registration needs to change the Lifestyle from the default (Singleton) so that it gets recreated for each request (and the dependencies are re-evaluated) - Transient or PerWcfSession would work.

Also, because we require a session, the binding needs to change from the basicHttpBinding to something that that supports sessions:

```
Component.For<IHelloWorldService>()
    .ImplementedBy<HelloWorldService>()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .AsWcfService(
        new DefaultServiceModel()
            .AddBaseAddresses(baseAddress)
            .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("myBinding"))
            .PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())
    )
```

Which makes the final code look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;

using Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace SelfHost
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string name);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
    {
        private readonly PerSession _perSession;

        public HelloWorldService(PerSession perSession)
        {
            _perSession = perSession;
        }

        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello, {0} {1}", name, _perSession.Info());
        }
    }

        public class PerSession
        {
            private readonly string _now;

            public PerSession()
            {
                _now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }

            public string Info()
            {
                return _now;
            }
        }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();

            container.Register(
                Component.For<PerSession>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
                Component.For<IHelloWorldService>()
                    .ImplementedBy<HelloWorldService>()
                    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
                    .AsWcfService(
                        new DefaultServiceModel()
                            .AddBaseAddresses(baseAddress)
                            .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding()).At("myBinding"))
                            .PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())
                    )
                );

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you defining "myBinding" and the base address? Cheers

Comment: myBinding is defined in the Program class in the question

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, I don't suppose you could update your answer with this code? I'm having issues myself getting the bindings to bind to a specific address. Cheers

Comment: There you go! The "mybinding" is just the name of the binding. There is nothing else defined in the .config file